# Java:JSON to map using GSON

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I have a string like this

```
{"key0":"value0","key1":"value1","key0":"value3"}
```

I want to store it in a map and the desired result is {"key0":"value3","key1":"value1"}

Using org.json.JsonObject: I passed the string to the constructor and Duplicate key exception is thrown

Using GSON: Same exception when I tried through new Gson.fromJson(string,Type)

Using Jackson: It does work

Is there a workaround to achieve the same using JSONObject and Gson

Comment: you do realize that having the same key will cause to overwrite the value. I think, even though it works in jackson, you cannot guarantee what the value for a specific key is if the key is repeated in the input.

Comment: Can you also elaborate the logic behind the desired result? Is it just that the last value for some key in order they happen to appear in JSON file/string? So you assume that "value0" is inserted first in map and then "value3" overwrites it? Order is not garanteed anywhere I think. But you should also consider that your example is not a valid JSON if it represents a map. On the other way : how can you serialize a map and have two values for the same key in result JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly if you first cast that json to an `Object` and then to a `Map<String,String>` your desired result happens:

```
String json = "{\"key0\":\"value0\",\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key0\":\"value3\"}";
Gson gson = new Gson();
Object obj = gson.fromJson(json, Object.class);
try {
    Map<String,String> map = (Map<String, String>)obj;
    // Outputs...
    // key0=value3
    // key1=value1
    for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue());
    }
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: It worked.But can anyone explain ? Couldn't find much in docs. My understanding is that second agruement of .fromJson specified how to interpret the deserialised object.Since Map doesn't allow duplicate entries it threw an error.Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: It looks like `gson.fromJson()` actually first casts the result to `Object` so by default you can use `Object` as the return type of `gson.fromJson()`.  The actual type of the `Object` I believe will either be `LinkedTreeMap` (which is what a json object is) or `ArrayList`.  You would have to look at the Gson source code to see how they convert.  Either way, you can always use `Object` and then examine the type of that.

Answer (score 1):

GSON uses `MapTypeAdapterFactory` to deserialioze map. Below is a short excerpt of its source code where a new entry is put in a map:

```
V replaced = map.put(key, value);
if (replaced != null) {
    throw new JsonSyntaxException("duplicate key: " + key);
}
```

Knowing that there is at least one way to bypass this strict behavior: create your own map that overrides the method `put(..)` to return always null, like:

```
public class DuploMap extends HashMap<String, String>{
    @Override
    public String put(String key, String value) {
        super.put(key, value);
        return null; 
    }
}
```

then deserailizing to it like:

```
gson.fromJson(JSON, DuploMap.class);
```

will not throw that exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GSON's JsonReader if you do not mind the manual effort.

On the plus side:

- faster (no reflection, no casts)
- fully under your control

--

```
String json = "{"key0":"value0","key1":"value1","key0":"value3"}";
JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(json));
HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>()
String currKey;
try {
    while(jsonReader.hasNext()){
        JsonToken nextToken = jsonReader.peek();
           if(JsonToken.NAME.equals(nextToken)){
               currKey = jsonReader.nextName();
           }
           if(JsonToken.STRING.equals(nextToken)){
               map.put(currKey, jsonReader.nextString())
           }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```